# UITableView causes this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key exception

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using Xamrin with MvvmCross and I have encountered the weirdest problem when deploying to device, I have a perfectly working page but once I add a UITableView to it I start to get the

```
   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant 
   for the key
```

If I remove the outlets connection to the UITableView everything works fine. On the simulator everything works perfecly

I have no idea what is wrong :(
Here is the code for the binind (altough It never gets there...)

```
var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource (UsersSearchList, PeopleSearchTableCell.Key, PeopleSearchTableCell.Key);
UsersSearchList.Source = source;
            var source2 = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource (RecomendedUsersList, PeopleSearchTableCell.Key, PeopleSearchTableCell.Key);
            RecomendedUsersList.Source = source2;
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainPage, MainPageViewModel> ();
            set.Bind (source).To (vm => vm.UserSearchViewModel.Users);
            set.Bind (source2).To (vm => vm.RecomendedUsersSearchViewModel.Users);              
            set.Apply ();
```

I wanted to attache the xib file but its to big...

I have another UITableView in this page which works perfectly

I have seen manu solutions to this but non worked for me...

Please help...

Comment: try clean product,delete and reinstall.

Comment: Have tried that... also tried release, debug and ad-hoc. for now I am adding the table views by code and everything works, at least I have that :(

Answer (score 1):

Check your .h and .m files for this view for errors (deleted outlets not removed properly etc), check to make sure there are no connections that should not be there by right clicking on the controls or on the view bar, clean your project in both x-code and after synchronizing xamarin. This 95% of the time fixes the issue for me. (For some reason I have even had to clean in xamarin twice before the error goes away, maybe doing it too fast before it can referesh).